# How can I make a dynamic select box?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've three select-box here. How can I make this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uLQ2VeE.png]

```
<select class="form-control input-lg">
              <option value="1">abcd</option>
              <option value="2">efgh</option>
              <option value="2">ijkl</option>
              <option value="2">mnop</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control input-lg">
              <option value="10">desk</option>
              <option value="20">pen</option>
              <option value="30">pc</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control input-lg">
              <option value="100"></option>
              <option value="200"></option>
              <option value="300"></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You want inter-related select box.. what have you tried?

Comment: Please describe your question in brief. I can not understand your question.

Comment: Usually, you'd use ajax for this. Load the content of `<select> 2` based on the selection of `<select> 1` and the content of `<select> 3` based on the selection of `<select> 2`

Comment: I know little English. I'm sorry. I do not want the inter-related select box. Example: If user selected the PEN. The user see the Blue Pen, Yellow Pen and Red Pen. OR If user selected the PC. The user see the A pc, B pc and C pc. http://i.imgur.com/lTsDwb0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally this is an event driven question.

You want to populate the secondary select based on the first. You can do this with a jquery change event.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

On change, you initiate a callback function that populates the second select box, from there the population of the third is just the same concept.

A high level explanation is as such:

```
<select id="select1" class="form-control input-lg">
          <option value="1">abcd</option>
          <option value="2">efgh</option>
          <option value="2">ijkl</option>
          <option value="2">mnop</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="form-control input-lg">
</select>

<script>  
  $('#select1').change(function(){
    alert("Something has changed");
    // RUN SOME OTHER FUNCTION TO POPULATE THE SECOND SELECT BOX

    // Grab the dom element of the second select
    var select2 = $("#select2");

    // iterate your data, here an array with an element, and populate the select element
    $.each(['some data'], function() {
        select2.append($("<option />").val("Something").text("Something else"));
    });

  })
</script>
```

Note: For this you will obviously have to include JQuery library in your code
This is also considerably inefficient, but the improvements would take too long to explain in such an open question.